# Android 11 su get global access with inherited namespace

Tags: android, root, su

I have a root app that should change some files in another app. My phone is rooted (Samsung Galaxy S21+ 5G) and I use the following code to execute a `ls` as test, but I only get the own app directory as long as I have set Mount Namespace Mode to "inherit the requester's namespace". I only see all directories with Global Namespace. The thing I'm not understanding is why I can see all apps using Termux app (su; ls /data/user/0/) even with inherit namespace.

Is there a way to make it work with default namespace setting in Magisk (inherit namespace)?

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes("ls /data/user/0/\n");
os.writeBytes("exit\n");
os.flush();
os.close();
p.waitFor();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
char[] buffer = new char[4096];
StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
while (true) {
  int read = reader.read(buffer);
  int read2 = read;
  if (read <= 0) {
      System.out.println(output.toString());
  }
  output.append(buffer, 0, read2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using magisk su, there is a parameter:

`--mount-master                force run in the global mount namespace`

So you change change the command to `su --mount-master`